# How do I define RequiredModules in a PowerShell module manifest (psd1)?

Tags: powershell, module, manifest

I'm trying to create a simple dependency between two PowerShell modules, but I'm getting the syntax or *something* wrong.

`Module1.psd1`:

```
@{
    RootModule        = 'Module1.psm1'
    ModuleVersion     = '1.0'
    GUID              = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
    Author            = 'uw'
    FunctionsToExport = @()
    CmdletsToExport   = @()
    VariablesToExport = '*'
    AliasesToExport   = @()
}
```

`Module2.psd1`:

```
@{
    RootModule        = 'Module2.psm1'
    ModuleVersion     = '1.0'
    GUID              = '22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222'
    Author            = 'uw'
    FunctionsToExport = @()
    CmdletsToExport   = @()
    VariablesToExport = '*'
    AliasesToExport   = @()
    RequiredModules   = @(
                          @{
                            ModuleName = "Module1"; 
                            ModuleVersion = "1.0"; 
                            Guid = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
                           }
                         )
}
```

The module manifest for `Module2` defines that `Module2` depends on `Module1`.

When running `Test-ModuleManifest Module2.psd1`, I get the following error:

```
Test-ModuleManifest : The specified RequiredModules entry 'Module1' in the module manifest 'Module2.psd1' is invalid. 
Try again after updating this entry with valid values.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that `Test-ModuleManifest` expects all required modules to be installed on the local system.

So the fix is to install `Module1`, then validate the manifest of `Module2`.

See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/blob/90c5a3d4c8a2e698d38cfb5ef4b1c44d79180d66/Tests/PSGetPublishModule.Tests.ps1#L1470.

Answer (score 4):

Your question inspired **[this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7495)**, which **proposes introducing an option to *restrict* checking to whether a module is (syntactically) *well-formed*, as opposed to whether all modules referenced can be *found and loaded***.

<sup>The linked issue is primarily about a related *bug*: `Test-ModuleManifest` currently ignores dependencies on a *specific version* of a required module - *any* locally available version passes the test.</sup>

As an alternative to your own **workaround** (installing all required modules locally first), the following approach is a **simpler** stopgap:

```
# Run Test-ModuleManifest and collect any errors in variable $errs while
# suppressing immediate error output.
Test-ModuleManifest ./Module1.psd1 -ErrorVariable errs 2>$null

# Remove the errors relating to the 'RequiredModules' key, which we want to ignore.
$errs = $errs | ? { $_.ToString() -notmatch '\bRequiredModules\b' }

# Output any remaining errors.
$errs | % { Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_ }

# Determine success:
# Testing the manifest succeeded, if no errors other than the anticipated
# one relating to 'RequiredModules' occurred.
$ok = $errs.Count -eq 0
```

Comment: Still a bug in PowerShell 5.1, create a manifest for module on a network share where the required modules are also in the default PowerShell/Modules path works. Remove those local modules and you cannot update the manifest even if the required module is on the network share

Comment: @kevinsky: Given that _Windows PowerShell_ will see no new development and only critical bug fixes, I doubt it will ever be fixed there. I expect it will be fixed in PowerShell _Core_ at some point, but it's unclear when that will happen (definitely not for the upcoming v7.0)